# Hashing an IP address to a number in [0, H)

Tags: python, ip-address, hash, zlib, crc32

I'm using Python-2.6. I have very little knowledge of hash functions.

I want to use a CRC hash function to hash an IP address like '128.0.0.5' into the range [0, H). Currently I'm thinking of doing

```
zlib.crc32('128.0.0.5')%H.
```

Is this okay? There's a few ques. you could try and answer...

- does it make any diff. if I hash '128.0.0.5' or its binary '0001110101010..' whatever that is or without the '.'s
- zlib.crc32 returns a signed integer. Does modding (%) a neg. with a positive H always give a pos no?
- Does %-ing by H affect how good the hash function is? ( I mean is that the best I could do for the available space, with the available xlib.crc32)

Thanks!

Comment: How big is H and how do you want to deal with collisions?

Comment: An IP address is already an unsigned 32 bit integer. What exactly are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I'm hashing because I don't want to use 32 bits for storing the IP address, rather only log(H, 2), and I'm going to do some more stuff to the hashed values and I want them to be random. H will use much fewer than 32 bits, around 8 or 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does it make any diff. if I hash '128.0.0.5' or its binary '0001110101010..' whatever that is or without the '.'s

Not really.

> zlib.crc32 returns a signed integer. Does modding (%) a neg. with a positive H always give a pos no?

Yes.

> Does %-ing by H affect how good the hash function is? ( I mean is that the best I could do for the available space, with the available xlib.crc32)

You'd better use all the bits of the checksum to make up for their lack of an "avalanche effect".  Single-digit variations such as `192.168.1.1`, `192.168.1.2`, etc might produce differences only in the first bits of the checksum, and since `%` cares only about the last bits, hashes will collide.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you want to hash an IP address into a number?  They already have a native integer representation. For example, using [netaddr](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/netaddr/):

```
>>> import netaddr
>>> ip = netaddr.IPAddress('192.168.1.1')
>>> ip.value
3232235777
>>> netaddr.IPAddress(3232235777)
IPAddress('192.168.1.1')
```

Comment: +1 for not using a hash at all. would give +1 for using the netaddr too

Comment: I'm hashing because I don't want to use 32 bits for storing the IP address, rather only log(H, 2), and I'm going to do some more stuff to the hashed values and I want them to be random. I didn't know about netaddr though. Looks like it changes the IP address from "base 256" to base 10, neat!

Comment: If you want to hash a 32-bit number to a lower size, you're going to lose resolution as others have suggested. The netaddr` module is not doing any tricks, just providing a Python interface. The entire range of IPv4 addresses (0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255) each represent an unsigned 32-bit integer from 0-4294967295 (2**32). The same goes for IPv6, except that each integer is 128 bits (2**128).

Answer (score 2):

ad 1) It will yield different results, but does not effect the quality of the hash.

ad 2) It will always yield a positive number or zero.

ad 3) As you limit the number of possible buckets, it does affect the quality of the hash.

In general: About how large is your H? Remember that a IPv4 address is nothing more than a 32-bit value. 192.168.0.1 is just a more human readable byte-wise representation. So if your H is larger than 4294967295, there will be no need of hashing.

Comment: Thanks, my H will be much lesser, prob. around 2**8 or so.