# Is there a function for Converting IP address to decimal number in python?

Tags: python, ip, decimal

Is there any function or API or method that will convert a doted IP string to decimal number?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756063/hashing-an-ip-address-to-a-number-in-0-h/6756395#6756395

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure what is the decimal number you really want, but take a look at `socket.inet_aton`. It will give you string with binary representation of the IP address in network byte order. If you want to get a regular integer out of it, you could use `struct.unpack` with either `"!I"` or `"I"`, depending on which byte order you're interested in.

Example:

```
import socket, struct
print struct.unpack("!I", socket.inet_aton("127.0.0.1"))[0]
```

Prints: `2130706433`.